# Error updating React Navigation from React Native

Tags: xcode, react-native

I have the following problem.

When updating the React Navigation of a React Native project I can no longer execute the build command `react-native run-ios`.

The following error is displayed to me when I execute the command:[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can't upgrade react-navigation from 4.x to 5.x directly.

Here is a offical guide for upgrade react-navigation to 5.x: [Upgrading from 4.x](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/upgrading-from-4.x/)